# How to reduce heroku slug size in react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, size

So I have a react app linked to heroku with the git repositry. Now the problem is that the slug size is exceeding so its not building on heroku hence not deploying either. So I created a .slugignore text file in the root directory of my react app and typed node_modules in it like so:

[image]

But doing this isn't working at all, the slug size remains the same. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? I really need to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this buildpack to your heroku app:

[heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean]
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean

and then add **.slug-post-clean** file to your project root directory:

```
src
public
README.md
node_modules
```

Comment: That package is no longer actively, the succeeded by [this one](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/opencounter/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean) it seems.