# Reduce heroku slug size while whitelisting 'serve' and its dependencies

Tags: reactjs, heroku, caching, create-react-app

I have a React app (CRA) that exceeds heroku's maximum slug size soft limit (300MB), so I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908609/8274517) to reduce the slug size:

1. `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/opencounter/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean.git`
2. Add the file `.slug-post-clean` at the project root:

```
src
public
node_modules
```

But, as the same time, I'm serving my app using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve), `package.json`:

```json
...
"dependencies": {
...
  "serve": "^12.0.1",
...
}, 
...
"scripts" : {
  "start": "serve -s build",
}
```

Excluding `node_modules` altogether will also exclude `serve`, making heroku unable to serve my app.

How to reduce heroku slug size while whitelisting 'serve' and its dependencies ?

For now, I'm excluding some big independent packages (*e.g.* `@mui`, `@testing-library`, *etc.*), but that's a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After excluding `node-modules/.cache`, the slug size has been reduced down 90%  (~400M). So the solution is quite simple:

In `.slug-post-clean`, add:

```
node-modules/.cache
```

Comment: In my case, is not reducing, my final slug is over 300MB, I think .slug-post-clean is not working properly, when I check my slug, the folders that i technically ignored are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `heroku-cleanup` command in your `package.json` like this:

```
script: {
   "start": "serve -s build",
   "heroku-cleanup": "rm -rf node_modules src"
}
```

It's not necessary any buildpack, you can see more information in heroku support page:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support